# How to overload Inc (Dec) operators in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, operator-overloading, increment

[Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)) says that it is possible to overload the Inc and Dec operators; I see no valid way to do it. Here are attempts to overload the Inc operator; some attempts lead to compile errors, some to runtime access violation (Delphi XE):

```
program OverloadInc;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TMyInt = record
    FValue: Integer;
//    class operator Inc(var A: TMyInt);   DCC error E2023
    class operator Inc(var A: TMyInt): TMyInt;
    property Value: Integer read FValue write FValue;
  end;

class operator TMyInt.Inc(var A: TMyInt): TMyInt;
begin
  Inc(A.FValue);
  Result:= A;
end;

type
  TMyInt2 = record
    FValue: Integer;
    class operator Inc(A: TMyInt2): TMyInt2;
    property Value: Integer read FValue write FValue;
  end;

class operator TMyInt2.Inc(A: TMyInt2): TMyInt2;
begin
  Result.FValue:= A.FValue + 1;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  A: TMyInt;

begin
  A.FValue:= 0;
  Inc(A);
  Writeln(A.FValue);
end;

procedure Test2;
var
  A: TMyInt2;
  I: Integer;

begin
  A.FValue:= 0;
//  A:= Inc(A);  DCC error E2010
  Writeln(A.FValue);
end;

begin
  try
    Test;     // access violation
//    Test2;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The signature of the operator is wrong. It should be:

```
class operator Inc(const A: TMyInt): TMyInt;
```

or

```
class operator Inc(A: TMyInt): TMyInt;
```

You cannot use a `var` parameter.

This program

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TMyInt = record
    FValue: Integer;
    class operator Inc(const A: TMyInt): TMyInt;
    property Value: Integer read FValue write FValue;
  end;

class operator TMyInt.Inc(const A: TMyInt): TMyInt;
begin
  Result.FValue := A.FValue + 1;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  A: TMyInt;
begin
  A.FValue := 0;
  Inc(A);
  Writeln(A.FValue);
end;

begin
  Test;
  Readln;
end.
```

produces this output:

```
1
```

**Discussion**

This is a rather unusual operator when overloaded. In terms of usage the operator is an in-place mutation. However, when overloaded, it works like an addition operator with an implicit addend of one.

So, in the code above this line:

```
Inc(A);
```

is effectively transformed into

```
A := TMyInt.Inc(A);
```

and then compiled.

If you are wanting to maintain true in-place mutation semantics, and avoid the copying associated with this operator, then I believe that you need to use a method of the type.

```
procedure Inc; inline;
....
procedure TMyInt.Inc;
begin
  inc(FValue);
end;
```

Comment: Mutation of const parameter looks strange, isn't it? Also the function prototype with return value to be ignored?

Comment: It looks like mutation at the call site, but the compiler translates `Inc(MyInt)` into `MyInt := TMyInt.Inc(MyInt);` Yes it's very strange. I would not overload `Inc` and `Dec`.